# iPhone calendar events not showing in iCal (Snow Leopard, iPhone 4S)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, itunes, iphone, ios, calendar.app

My wife's iPhone4S is all set up with iCloud synching, etc.  However, she does not have Lion yet so she can't sync to iCal through the cloud.

Anyway, in iTunes the Sync Calendar option is checked, and her events from iCal are showing up on the iPhone just fine.  However, the events in iCal are not showing on the iPhone. I've synced many times and restarted, updated all software involved... no luck.  I've been looking on the Googles for answers but most posts are to do with MobileMe, or with new iCloud based stuff, etc.

Details:

OSX 10.6.8 10K549

iOS 5.0.1 9A405

iCal 4.0.4 1395.7

iTunes 10.5.1 (42)

Comment: I'd also like to know what I can do to make iCal (snow leopard) work better with ios6 in general